# Background image not displaying without localhost

Tags: html, css

Everything worked fine on local host and now I have created a repo and uploaded it doesn't seem to be working.

https://michael-hands.github.io/TestWeb/

I changed my folder set up as I thought the problem was in the path of the background url and also tried to do it with inline html styling but neither work for me.

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here, not your web site which will change when fixed and your question and the answers useless. [mcve]

Comment: press F12, go to network - see you get a 404 on your image at https://michael-hands.github.io/assets/background.jpg using `background-image: url(../assets/background.jpg);` - remove the `../` and delete the question which is useless to anyone but you

Answer (score 0):

In css file change the background from

```
background-image: url("../assets/background.jpg");
```

To:

```
background-image: url("../background.jpg");
```

For inline Code use

```
style="background-image: url(./assets/background.jpg);"
```